# search through all lenses

Tags: lenses

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with some additional lenses.

Is it possible to search though all lenses at the same time? 
For example when I type "Tom" it looks for all calendar events (through Calendar events lenses), all Empathy contacts and all music titles contains this string.

Please advice me, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but there would need to be an extra bit of code to bind together the background services which search in various pots of data and the lens front end you'd like these delivered to.

This would be an 'all in one' lens. And you can learn about making them here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/lenses-and-scopes/

The alternative method is to hack the existing lens definitions so they all appear in the home menu when you search there. There is work here though, so look for someone else who might have done with job for you already. (and post it here!)